# UICollectViewFlowLayout minimumInteritemSpacing fails after adding and removing another view controller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Summary

1. Collection view shows 4 images.  There are more, but they're not displayed yet.
2. Animate another view on top of the collection.  Remove it.
3. Come back. Scroll the UICollectionView to display beyond the original
4. They don't follow FlowLayout rules.

DETAILS of what does work.

1. Restart the app.
2. Go to the VC that contains the UIcollectionView
3. DO  SCROLL to show the 5th and 6th items.
4. Add another VC on top of this one:

> ```
> [self addChildViewController:formName];
> [self.view addSubview:formName.view];
>
>
> // Build new frame.  Only change the Y position
> CGRect newFrame = formName.view.frame;
> newFrame.origin.y = 0;
>
> [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
>                  animations:^
>  {
>     formName.view.frame = newFrame;
>  }];
> ```

5. Immediately remove that view

> [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
>                        animations:^
>
> ```
>  {
>      formName.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.scrollHeight3,
> ```
>
> self.screenWidth,self.scrollHeight3);
>        }
>
> ```
> completion:^(BOOL finished)
>  {
>      [formName.view removeFromSuperview];
>      [formName removeFromParentViewController];
>  }];
> ```

6. Scroll the UICollectionView. The 5th and 6th entries are still good.

DETAILS OF WHAT DOESN'T WORK

But, when the 5th and 6th entries are not displayed right away, this happens:

1. Restart the app.
2. Go to the VC that contains the UIcollectionView
3. DO NOT SCROLL to show the 5th and 6th item.
4. Add another VC on top of this one:
5. Immediately remove that view
6. NOW scroll UICollectionView to show the 5th and 6th entries for the first time.  The new images are not following the rules. The cells are substantially larger than the FlowLayout allows.

I have logged all the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` parameters. They are unchanged.  The cell size is unchanged.  `minimumInteritemSpacing` is still 12.0.  I've spent a couple hours on this.  I am stuck.

I'm sorry I don't have the reputation to post images.

Here's how I create the cells:

`UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Here's how I create the UICollectionView

```
photoFrame = floor ((model.screenWidth - 3 * model.detailPadding)/2 - 1);
verticalSpacing = floor (model.screenWidth * 0.04f);

flowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
// flowLayout.delegate = self;
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(photoFrame, photoFrame + 25.0)];
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = verticalSpacing;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = model.detailPadding;
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake (model.detailPadding, model.detailPadding,
                           floor (model.screenWidth - 2 * model.detailPadding),
                           floor (model.screenHeight - model.navBarHeight - model.topBarHeight - 2* model.detailPadding));

// Create data for collection views
tileView = [[UICollectionView  alloc ] initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
tileView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
tileView.delegate = self;
tileView.dataSource = self;
[tileView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[self.view addSubview:tileView];
```